# Why can't get lexbuf.lex_buffer_len in ocaml's compiler code?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

I have this prog:

```
let ()=
 let filename = "/home/wk/prog/LocationTest/b.ml" in
 Location.input_name := filename ;
 let readhandle = open_in filename in
 let buf = Lexing.from_channel readhandle in
 Printf.printf "%d" (buf.lex_buffer_len) ;
```

it works fine

but if I use 
   Printf.printf "%d" (buf.lex_buffer_len)

in ocaml's 4.07 compile source code /driver/pparse.ml line 181:

```
let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel ic in
Printf.printf "%d" (lexbuf.lex_buffer_len) ;
```

then I "make world",I got error:

Error (warning 40): lex_buffer_len was selected from type Lexing.lexbuf.
It is not visible in the current scope, and will not 
be selected if the type becomes unknown.

why it can't used in there?how to print lex_buffer_len in this situation?thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the text of the error, the field `lex_buffer_len` belongs to a type that is defined in the `Lexing` module. The proper way to refer to it is thus to write `lexbuf.Lexing.lex_buffer_len` or to `open Lexing` beforehand.

OCaml lets you do `lexbuf.lex_buffer_len` when there is no ambiguity (and `lexing.cmi` is in one of the directories where it searches for signatures, but for a standard library module this is always the case unless you explicitly tell it to ignore stdlib), but, as it can be dangerous (if at some point you define a type with a similarly named field, weird errors will occur), this is subject to a warning, and it appears that the options given to OCaml during the bootstrap of the compiler make warning 40 an error (see options `-w` and `-warn-error` in the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/comp.html#sec283))